# ArithmeticError when using sum on an associated column

Tags: ecto

I'm trying to add the sum of all ratings to a post. But I'm getting an error: `ArithmeticError: bad argument in arithmetic expression`. I believe that's because not all `Post` will have `ratings` associated with it. And then it won't be able to `sum` the values in those non-existent ratings.

How would I go about setting the rating to `0` if there are no `ratings` associated with a `post` in the database?

Query:

```
from post in Post,
left_join: rating in assoc(post, :ratings),
group_by: post.id,
select: %{post | rating: sum(rating.value)}
```

Schemas:

```
schema "posts" do
    field :rating, :integer, virtual: true
    has_many :ratings, MyApp.Rating
end

schema "ratings" do
    field :value, :integer
    belongs_to :post, MyApp.Post
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the Elixir Slack channel I managed to solve it by using the postgres function `coalesce()`.

> The COALESCE function returns the first of its arguments that is not null. Null is returned only if all arguments are null. It is often used to substitute a default value for null values when data is retrieved for display.

Armed with this newfound knowledge I rewrote my query and it seems to work as intended:

```
from post in Post,
left_join: rating in assoc(post, :ratings),
group_by: post.id,
select: %{post | rating: sum(fragment("coalesce(?,0)", rating.value))}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also a [coalesce](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#coalesce/2) function in Ecto

```
from post in Post,
left_join: rating in assoc(post, :ratings),
group_by: post.id,
select: %{post | rating: sum(coalesce(rating.value, 0))}
```